# Stop Jsoup from encoding

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to parese an URL with JSoup which contains the following Text: `Ætterni`.
After parsing the document the same string looks like that: `&AElig;tterni`.

How do I prevent this form happening? I want the document 1:1 exactly like it was.

Code:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
String docEncoding=doc.outputSettings().charset().name();
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(localLink),docEncoding);
writer.write(doc.html());
writer.close();
```

Answer (score 6):

Use
    `doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(EscapeMode.xhtml);`
for avoiding entities conversion.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be not utilizing the Jsoup's powers in any way. I'd just stream the HTML plain using [`java.net.URL`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html). This way you have a 1:1 copy of the response.

```
InputStream input = new URL(url).openStream();
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(localLink);
// Now copy input to output the usual Java IO way.
```

You should **not** use `Reader`/`Writer` for this as this may malform the characters of sources in unknown encoding, because the platform default encoding would be used instead.

Comment: I'm using Jsoup for an application that stores a website so I'm using the powers of Jsoup a lot but it wouldn't make sense to post like 600 LoC :o. I just simplified my problem. So I can use OutputStreams with Josup to?

Comment: So, you are traversing and manipulating the HTML using Jsoup? You told that you want a 1:1 copy. I initially expected that you're using Jsoup just to figure the charset because you incorrectly used a `Writer` to save the content. Well, you can't prevent it from encoding special characters. What exactly is the problem you have when Jsoup does that? Jsoup by the way almost never gives a 1:1 copy back by `html()` because it by default adds/sanitizes some tags as well to make it valid HTML and well-formed XML.

Comment: Yes im complettly rewriting the HTML so it can be used form a local file system. The problem I have is that it manipulates special characters in a way that they are no longer recogniced as urls. For example it changes the url /Mitglieder/Höttur.jpg to /Mitglieder/H & o u m l ; ttur.jpg (added spaces). I can not retrieve the changed url because its no longer valid..

Comment: As far as I see and know, Jsoup does not support it. You may want to post a feature request at https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues. Edit: that it is doing it for link URLs seems a bug to me. You'd like to report it as such.

Comment: Okay thank you for your time and feedback. I will have to write a custom function then to return the urls back to normal. I will report it also.

Comment: I just got some feedback, basically its only the .html() function that encodes the text. The attribute values are unencoded :)